# Python TypeError : 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Tags: python

I learn to Emotion Recognition program in python

I tried to [here source](https://github.com/PiotrDabr/facemoji/blob/master/prepare_model.py), I ran the code

```
('size of training set is:', 379, 'images')
predicting classification set
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "prepare_model.py", line 72, in <module>
correct = run_recognizer()
File "prepare_model.py", line 63, in run_recognizer
correct = sum(1 for id, image in enumerate(prediction_data) if fishface.predict(image)[0] == prediction_labels[id])
ict(image)[0] == prediction_labels[id])
File "prepare_model.py", line 63, in <genexpr>
correct = sum(1 for id, image in enumerate(prediction_data) if fishface.predict(image)[0] == prediction_labels[id])
TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

I use Ubuntu 16.04LTS 64bit / python 2.7 / opencv3.1.0 + contrib

help me please...

i changed in line 63

`correct = sum(1 for id, image in enumerate(prediction_data) if fishface.predict(image)[0] == prediction_labels[id])`

to

`correct = sum(1 for id, image in enumerate(prediction_data) if fishface.predict[image][0] == prediction_labels[id])`

but doesn't work...

How can fix that ??

Comment: I changed `correct = sum(1 for id, image in enumerate(prediction_data))` it worked... but... I  am not trust me...

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
fishface.predict(image)[0] ...
```

shows you predict is a function. 
When you change (...) to [...], python interprets `predict[]` as a list on which the first element (index 0) has to be set to a value. Therefore the above error. 
So in Python, x(...) is a function call, while x[..] is a list or dict on which an element is reqested.